# from 16bit unsigned value to minutes and seconds

Tags: performance, assembly, time, microcontroller, pic

I'm writing some PIC assembly code to compute the remaining time of a CD track based on elapsed minutes and seconds and total track length (16 bit unsigned value, in seconds).

The elapsed minutes and seconds are two 8bit unsigned values (two GPR register), the total track length is a two bytes value (hi-byte and lo-byte).

I need to compute the remaining time, expressed in minutes and seconds.
I tried computing the total elapsed seconds (elapsed_minutes * 60 + elapsed_seconds) subtracting it to the total track length. Now I face the problem how to convert back such result in a MM:SS format. Do I have to divide by 60? take the quotient (minutes) and the remainder (seconds)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you divide by 60 to get minutes and the remainder is seconds. It's just algebra, not magic!

Comment: Of course, no magic in there! :-) do you advice any good algorithm to do so? how to do repeated subtractions over a two byte value?